# Add const to type if template arg is const

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a class:

```
struct Foo {
  vector<float> data;
};
```

and I have a templated function that takes a Foo&:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& arg) {
  using ftype = float *;    // <-- would like this to be const float * if T is const
  ftype ptr = &arg.data[0];
  // ... do stuff with ptr ...
}
```

How can I make ptr be `const float *` iff T is const? I know about `add_const` and `is_const` but don't see how to use them here. (My real struct is more complicated and I don't have direct access to its internals; it's actually an OpenCV `cv::Mat`.)
I can use recent (C++14/C++17) features if needed.

I'll use it like this:

```
Foo foo1 = Foo();
f(foo1); // modifiable in f
const Foo cfoo = Foo();
f(cfoo); // const, should not be modifiable in f
```

Comment: If you wrote `auto ptr = &arg.data[0];`, `decltype(ptr)` would be `const float*`, no type traits needed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely, you actually just want the type of the expression `&arg.data[0]`, for which you can use `decltype`.

You can also use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to distinguish the cases.

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& arg) {
  // C++17: using ftype = std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<T>, const float *, float *>;
  using ftype = typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>::value, const float *, float *>::type;

  ftype ptr = &arg.data[0];
  // ... do stuff with ptr ...
}
```

If instead of `float *`, you had a second type parameter `U`, you would include `std::add_const`

```
template<typename T, typename U = float *>
void f(T& arg) {
  // C++17: using ftype = std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<T>, std::add_const_t<U>, U>;
  using ftype = typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>::value, typename std::add_const<U>::type, U>::type;
  // ... do stuff with ftype ...
}
```

I have marked where C++14 and C++17 has nicer syntax for equivalent use. C++11 lack of template `using`s and template variables results in verbose type functions :(.

Comment: The big win is for C++14: `_t` versus `typename` `::value`. C++17 is only `::value` vs `_v`.

Comment: @Jarod42 `_t` can be emulated in C++11:

`template <typename T> using add_const_t = typename std::add_const<T>::type;`

Answer (score 4):

```
template<class Src, class Dst>
using transcribe_const_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_const<Src>{}, Dst const, Dst>;
template<class Src, class Dst>
using transcribe_volatile_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_volatile<Src>{}, Dst volatile, Dst>;
template<class Src, class Dst>
using transcribe_cv_t = transcribe_const_t< Src, transcribe_volatile_t< Src, Dst> >;
```

now

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& arg) {
  using ftype = transcribe_cv_t<T, float>*;
  ftype ptr = &arg.data[0];
  // ... do stuff with ptr ...
}
```

does what you ask (and a bit more).